# Exoplayer equivalent for iOS - Video streaming similar to TikTok

Tags: video, streaming, xcode6, swift4, exoplayer

Is there a exoplayer equivalent for iOS for playing videos?

Or could someone help me know how does TikTok stream videos? Which video player does it use? I'm trying to stream videos in my app from firebase database, I'm using Swift but am stuck in choosing the right way to stream the videos. Could someone help me or tell me how to get started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native player in iOS is AVPlayer

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530

In the same way that Google's ExoPlayer is the usual default in Android (see @Manuel's excellent note in the comments below also), AvPlayer is the usual default in iOS and you can use it to play your streamed video, which will typically be in HLS .m3u8 file streaming format for Apple devices. Streams for Android devices are typically DASH .mpd file streaming format.

At this time Apple has also added in a new UI framework across devices including iOS - if you are using this it is worth searching for some good examples of AVPlayer integration, for example:

https://medium.com/@chris.mash/avplayer-swiftui-b87af6d0553

If you are using the more traditional UIKit then Apple provide some simple examples you can test with, substituting your test steam in the code below (from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos?language=objc ):

```js
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Substitute your video stream URL here to test
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8") else {
        return
    }
    // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that Exoplayer is NOT the default media player in Android as it is not part of the Android framework. Android's MediaPlayer is the default. Exoplayer was developed as a seperate library by Google. Is there something similar for ios ? As in similar I mean something that offers the same features as Exoplayer.

Comment: @Amroelaswar The 3rd party library Exoplayer is used widely in Android because the default video player is a primitive implementation and the variety of Android hardware and custom OS flavors on the market make it a pain to develop and maintain a video player on Android. These are pain points virtually unknown to iOS developers. The default iOS frameworks provide the functionality of Exoplayer (and much more) out of the box. There is simply no need for Exoplayer. Another example, try to encode a video as mp4 on Android, it's pure pain. On iOS you do this natively and efficiently in one line.

Comment: @Manuel - great comment. I added a note in the answer to point people towards your comment as the history and the Android diversity makes it much more obvious why the iOS and Android video ecosystems are different. Same thing with Camera also, as an aside - for anyone interested, check out Camera 2 and Camera X history to see how tricky it can be in the Android domain to handle the wide variety of HW.

Comment: @Manuel this is 100% true. I was just pointing out that Exoplayer is a seperate library and when I first started of with Android at the time it wasn't as popular. I started of on iOS not long ago and was searching for an external library thinking that the player in the AVFoundation library was equivalent to Android's default MediaPlayer but I found out that it is much more advanced and there is no need for an external library on iOS like you do on Android. Also finding out that Exoplayer is the best choice is something that wasn't quite clear at the time especially for beginners.

Comment: So.. this wouldnt work if all my Videos are stored in a database as .mp4 ? Do I need to some how create .m3u8 lists ? Im confused in that part. Let's say I fetch an array with a bunch or .mp4 video urls. How can I load them and play as fast a Tiktok?

Comment: @omarojo - I think you may want to break this down and ask some new questions, but at  a high level: I don't have any knowledge of how Tik Tok is architected, but if you want to deliver a series of small videos with little delay from a server to a mobile device, then you have some options - e.g.  preload the next one while the current one is playing, combine on the server side and driver as a single stream etc